# How do I replace the fan of a dell latitude d630?

Tags: windows, fan, dell-latitude

I am having a hard time replacing the fan on the laptop model above. I don't want to pry and rip the fan.

Comment: You might be better off getting the machine serviced. See this tutorial - 27 steps to remove the fan.   https://www.parts-people.com/blog/2011/08/18/dell-latitude-d630-fan-removal-and-installation/

Comment: Download the Dell service manual from here>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-d630/docs